# How to run applet in Firefox without user permission

Tags: java, security, applet

I have a Java applet which I run into Firefox. Every time when I open the page with the applet I need to give to the applet permission to run. Can I somehow configure the applet to skip this and run without a permission? There are websites with applets which are loaded automatically without permission. One example: [example](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/servers-storage/servers/sparc-enterprise/m-series/m4000/overview/index.html) (click on 3-D Demo)

How I can configure this?

Comment: That applet doesn't load automatically with me. And hopefully no other applets will neither. It is a security concern implemented in most browsers these days.

Comment: I have not done it, but [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=433382&seqNum=2) it would seem that needing nothing granted `grant { }` and maybe signing might help.

Comment: *"..applets which are loaded automatically without permission. One example:"*  Given I saw a trust prompt, that is a bad example.  BTW - are you wanting this for *your own personal use* or for *your users*?

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's for internal corporate use.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can make the applet a [signed applet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet#Signed), but even this is still no guarantee the applet will be loaded without user permission - this still depends on specifics of the user's browser, Java applet plugin, and security settings.

I still got a popup box in Firefox for the applet you linked because the security settings on my computer are set to always show a permission warning before any applets run, signed or not.

Answer (score 1):

> It's for internal corporate use.

In that case, one way is to follow Nate's advice and configure it in the control panel.  But then, if you have access to the machines to do that, it would be better to install an altered [policy file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/step2.html) on each machine that relaxes the restriction ***only*** for code coming off the corporate site.

Comment: Alternatively, use a signed [tag:javawebstart] application and instruct users how to verify the fingerprint on a separate, corporate channel.